# R accessing both components of an vector from apply

Tags: r, apply

I have an `xtabs` object that looks like

```
            Cust_ID
Date        01/33  01/94  01/38  02/114 ...
2011-01-01    3.1    1.7   -2.3     4.8
2011-01-02    1.7    4.5    0.0     3.2 
2011-01-03    0.1    2.2    0.1    -0.1
```

I then create the object (I used a different function to `sum` in my original, so can't use Rowsum)

```
SumR <- apply(cast1,1,sum)
```

to get the object

```
2011-01-01  2011-01-02  2011-01-03
       7.3         9.4         2.3
```

My question is: how do I "access" the date field? For example, if I `plot(SumR)` I get a plot of the `7.3  9.4  2.3` but I want the x-axis to be correspond to the dates. I've tried `SumR[1,]` but get an "incorrect number of dimensions" error.

**Edit**
Following Aditya's suggestion, I can access the dates through the cast1 object itself:

```
cast1.df <- as.data.frame(cast1)
cast1.df[,1]
```

This seems quite dirty though. I'm a beginner with R so I'm not sure whether this method is good, or whether a more elegant solution exists.

Comment: Quick and dirty way would be to use cast1's Date column itself ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are names, stored as a character string.

You will need to do something like

```
plot(x = as.Date(names(sumR), format = '%Y-%m-%d'), y = sumR)
```